# Sub menus no longer displaying with mmenu

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress, menu, mmenu

I am using mmenu for a mobile menu of [this site](http://www.elektro-heat.com/).

The client has said that sub menus have stopped displaying after working for the past few months and I can't see any changes that would have effected it (other than maybe jquery version?)

*Does anyone have any advice on what the solution could be?*

Thanks.

Comment: The sub menu's are working fine for me. My predictable answer: tell them to clear their cache ;)

Comment: What browser youur client used?

Answer (score 0):

How did the menu look like when it was working? Because when I navigate to your website, I can see your submenu but the lay-out is not really nice.